# Swift 4: How to change font attributes of number in multiple UITextFields when .count > 3 and how to reverse calculation?

Tags: uitextfield, swift4, nsattributedstring

I have three UITextFields that will only contain a whole number between 0 and either 13066 or 3915 maximum. It's presented with a special font where `font1` at 50pt is larger than `font2` at 50pt so I only need to play around with the font file, not the size.

1) I need help finding a way to have the hundreds presented with `font2` but when the number **>= 1000**, the digits for thousands is presented with `font1`, while the hundreds still maintain `font2`. As this is a UITextField input, I need this to happen real-time.

[Animated picture of how the end result eventually will be!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi4ID.gif)

2) If you watch the animation, you'll see that each of the three fields totals to the field at the bottom. This is straight forward. However, I also want to reverse this, i.e filling in the total and the dials and digits should fill in as shown (half in each MAIN up to 3920 and remaining in CTR up to 13066). How do I code a functioning reversible calculation like that and avoid conflict?

This is what I got so far but it doesn't quite do what I want yet:

`class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var centerField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var main1Field: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var main2Field: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var totalField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //UITextField delegation
    centerField.delegate = self
    main1Field.delegate = self
    main2Field.delegate = self
    totalField.delegate = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

//Change font when number input exceeds 3 digits
func getAttributedString(for number: Int) -> NSAttributedString {
    let defaultAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "PMDG_777_DU_A", size: UIFont.labelFontSize)!
    ]
    let bigNumberAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "PMDG_777_DU_B", size: UIFont.labelFontSize)!
    ]

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(number)", attributes: defaultAttributes)
    if attributedString.length > 3 {
        let substr = attributedString.string.dropLast(3)
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, substr.utf16.count)
        attributedString.setAttributes(bigNumberAttributes, range: range)
    }

    return attributedString
}

//Hide keyboard when hitting Return
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

//Hide keyboard when tapping outside of field
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//Real-time calculation of entries made to the fields and output it live to the total
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    //Convert the String inserted into the fields into Int and create variables
    let centerFuel = Int(centerField.text!) ?? 0
    centerField.attributedText = getAttributedString(for: centerFuel)
    let main1Fuel = Int(main1Field.text!) ?? 0
    main1Field.attributedText = getAttributedString(for: main1Fuel)
    let main2Fuel = Int(main2Field.text!) ?? 0
    main2Field.attributedText = getAttributedString(for: main2Fuel)

    let total: Int = centerFuel + main1Fuel + main2Fuel
    totalField.attributedText = getAttributedString(for: total)
    return true
}
```

Comment: You need to set different `NSAttributedStringKey.font` with font 1 and font 2 applied on an range that is easily count: 0-3 from the end font 1, else font 2.

Comment: Ok, I'm pretty new to coding and I'm trying my best to learn. Any chance you can help by putting it in code? Doesn't it have to be an if {} somewhere?

Comment: str.count: 0-3 from the end font 1, else font 2. `dropLast(3)` and `dropFirst(str.count-3)` could help you separate into two string (and create 2 attributedString with correct font), then append both. Just check before if you can do the drop (since you can't put a negative value in it)

Comment: I think I see what you're saying but I'm too much a beginner to see how to complete it. Again, I just started to learn and have spent hours just to understand the NSAttributedString in the documentation. I need a full code solution as my guess work with bits and pieces doesn't take me anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSMutableAttributedString`:

```
func getAttributedString(for number: Int) -> NSAttributedString {
    precondition(number >= 0)

    let defaultAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    ]
    let bigNumberAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    ]

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(number)", attributes: defaultAttributes)
    if attributedString.length > 3 {
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length - 3)
        attributedString.setAttributes(bigNumberAttributes, range: range)
    }

    return attributedString
}
```

Then set the `attributedText` property on your label:

```
label.attributedText = getAttributedString(for: 13006)
```

And you can get result like this:

[image: big number]

Adjust the styles to taste!

Comment: What do I use in lieu of `systemFont`when I use embedded font files? In your little image, 066 should use "DU_B.ttf" and 13 should use "DU_A.ttf"

Comment: See [Adding a Custom Font to Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app)

Comment: Yea, sorry I was unclear. This I have already done. But in your code, `NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)`I believe I have to code it differently if I want to use those special fonts no? I'm thinking of the `UIFont.systemFont`part

Comment: It's there in Apple's example: `NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "CustomFont-Light", size: UIFont.labelFontSize)!`

Comment: Ok, thanks a bunch! I'll try this and see if I get it to work

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I'm a beginner and can't really see if I put your code right or if I need to call the function from somewhere. I've edited my question with the code I have so far...

Comment: Thanks, that worked when I put `myUITextField.attributedText = getAttributedString(for: Int)` after each `let` declaration. It behaves a bit weird though but I believe it's because of my calculation function. I have 3 text fields that totals real-time into a fourth. I must be doing something wrong, any chance you can look at my last `func`up there?

Comment: You are still using the plain text representation. Replace `totalField.text = "\(total)"` with `totalField.attributedText = getAttributedString(for: total)`

Comment: That I did do already. I don't think the `attributedString` is the problem, I think it's something with the real-time calculation. When I run the simulator, it's like the digits, although real-time, is one keystroke behind and thereby messes up the whole thing. First digit I put in either field, displays a zero in `totalField` even if it's not a zero. Typing one more digit, now the total shows the previous and so on... I can't figure out why. See updated code above how I run it now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample solution:

```
func attributedString(fromIntStr: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    print("Working with: \(fromIntStr)")

    let finalAttr = NSMutableAttributedString.init()

    let length = fromIntStr.count
    if length > 3 //we test this because we can't do dropLast(n) where n is negative
    {
        let start = String(fromIntStr.dropLast(3))

        let firstPart = NSAttributedString.init(string: start,
                                                attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)])
        finalAttr.append(firstPart)
    }

    var dropEnd = 0
    if length > 3 //we test this because we can't do dropFirst(n) where n is negative
    {
        dropEnd = length - 3
    }
    else
    {
        dropEnd = 0 //That's just an explicit value but it was already set by default
    }
    let end = String(fromIntStr.dropFirst(dropEnd))


    let lastPart = NSAttributedString.init(string: end,
                                           attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)])

    finalAttr.append(lastPart)

    //It seems that you want a right alignement and since we are using NSAttributedString we can do it by using ParagraphStyle
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.init()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .right
    finalAttr.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle,
                           value: paragraphStyle,
                           range: NSRange(location: 0, length: finalAttr.length))

    return finalAttr
}
```

It can be tested on Playground adding this at the end:

```
let values = ["", "9", "89", "789", "6789", "56789"]

let view = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 400))

for (i, str) in values.enumerated().reversed()
{
    let label = UILabel.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: i*50, width: 800, height: 50))
    let attr = attributedString(fromIntStr: str)
    label.attributedText = attr
    view.addSubview(label)
}

view
```

There are various way to do this but here is the logic I used:
 • Create a `NSMutableAttributedString`.
 • Separate the string in two strings (one for 0-999, the other one for the rest)
 • Create from them two `NSAttributedString` with the corresponding font
 • Append them to the `NSMutableAttributedString` previously created.

Of course this could be improved:
Is `dropFirst()`/`dropLast()` the best solutions?
I supposed that you add already a `String` value from a `Int` (I didn't do the conversion).

Another solution more classic would have been:
 • Create a `NSMutableAttributedString` from the whole `String`.
 • Apply small font on range last from last-3
 • Apply big font on range start to last -3

Last point be ommited if you apply the big font from the start on the whole string.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and let you know how it goes. Yes, I have three `@IBOutlets` (`centerLabel: UILabel!` as well as _main1Label_ and _main2Label_). I've converted the numbers that will be put in `centerText` with `let centerLabelString = String(centerText)`